# How to read an unsafe.pointer which the underlying memory is written by cgo?

Tags: go, cgo

- C definition

```c
void GetDataLocation(const void ** data) {
  // data is allocated in another function
  // the function provides the right pointer to the caller
  *data = pPermanentBuffer;
}
```

- Go

```golang
var data unsafe.Pointer
C.GetDataLocation(&data)
```

How do I dereference/cast the data written by the C function? Copy or copyless is fine.

The underlying data is allocated previously by the C code.

Old similar question: https://groups.google.com/g/golang-dev/c/JO99bwdOICs

Comment: You now have a pointer to the data. What is the structure of the data, and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Anything is fine, an array of bytes would be better but even just being able to read the first byte would be nice. `uint8(*data)` is obviously not allowed

Comment: An `unsafe.Pointer` can be converted to a pointer of any type you want. How are you determining the length here to get an array?

Comment: I know the length by a different way. `var test *[8]byte` `test = (*[8]byte)(data)` worked. Nevertheless, I can convert it to a slice.

Comment: `(*[8]byte)(data)` is the correct approach (usually extended to immediately making a slice off this array).